# Fine tuning this mysql search-function in PHP

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a classifieds website, where users can search for items.
The search should be in all fields with the name 'description' and 'headline'.

I am currently using 'like' syntax (SELECT * FROM db WHERE description LIKE '%string%' OR headline LIKE '%string%')

Problem is, if I have records with headlines like BMW it is enough to just type 'w' in the search field and they would be fetched.

I need to match entire words in the search string only.

If you need more input, I will update the Q...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MySQL's [full text searching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) or some third party full text search engine, like [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/). Both of this solutions will give you more power and control over the results you get from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using MySQL's REGEX (aka RLIKE) operator.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html